# Using of "spread"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, understanding

When I try to write or read it is okay. No problem. I can quitely understand. But when I think about it I get confused a little bit. For example look at the following sentence:

> They were supposed to spread the pain around.

It can be understood that by whom this work done. The work done by "They".

As to the sentence I got confused about, it is not obvious that by whom this work done by.

> And in recent days, viral misinformation has also spread on the platform.

If this sentence would have been "has also been spread on the platform" I could understand it. What I'm doing wrong and what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Spread can be a transitive verb (with an object) and and intransitive verb (no object).

> Transitive:
>
> You must spread the butter on the bread.
>
> They were supposed to spread the pain around (evenly share or
> distribute it).

> Intransitive:
>
> The news of the earthquake has spread fast in the country.
>
> An infectious disease can spread widely in a crowded place.
>
> Misinformation has also spread.